# Where is the preprocessing done in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Web programming n00b here.

Suppose I have a JavaScript object, particularly a HashMap, that needs instantiated when the page loads. Where should this be?

In general, I'm a little confused on where JavaScript tags are supposed to be. Suppose I want to define a JavaScript function in my head and then use `document.write()` in my body. It seems logical to write the following, since I'd be using JavaScript in both the head and body.

```
<html>
<script="text/javascript">
<head>
function foo() {};
</head>
<body>
document.write("Yo, dawg.");
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

But for some reason I've tried that and it doesn't work when I preview it in Chrome.

Comment: Just `<script>` is sufficient in any modern browser; you can drop the `type="text/javascript"` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have HTML in JavaScript like that. Wrap your `<script>` tags around your JavaScript only.

```
<html>
<head>
<script="text/javascript">
function foo() {};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script="text/javascript">document.write("Yo, dawg.");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

FYI, you should get familiar with tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). They'll help you with JavaScript development and making finding and diagnosing errors easier.

Answer (score 0):

You got the elements wrong

```
<html>
<head>
<script="text/javascript">
function foo() {};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script="text/javascript">
document.write("Yo, dawg.");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```